# Tricky sort by 2 different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this:

```
RefNum         Date        Status
----------------------------------
20276       12/7/2014     Approved
56332       13/7/2014     Approved
HS785       11/7/2014     Approved
52355       10/7/2014     Approved
HS566       15/7/2014     Approved
```

I need to sort it by `date` column. But tricky part is I also need the `refnum` which started with 'HS' to be at the bottom of the result sort by date as well.

So the result should be something like this

```
RefNum         Date        Status
----------------------------------
52355       10/7/2014     Approved
20276       12/7/2014     Approved
56332       13/7/2014     Approved
HS785       11/7/2014     Approved
HS566       15/7/2014     Approved
```

And I definitely can't do like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 
ORDER BY Date, RefNum
```

because it will return the list sort by the date first.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prepare to get your mind blown: you can use `case` in `order by`:

```
select * 
from tbl 
order by 
    case when RefNum like 'HS%' then 1 else 0 end, 
    Date
```

SQL Server allows you to use `case` almost anywhere - `group by`, `order by`, aggregate functions... it's a very powerful tool :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that your final query will be something like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl1
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN RefNum LIKE `HS%` THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
  Date,
  RefNum
```

So it will send whole `HS%` data to the end, and inside those groups will provide the order by `Date` and `RefNum`.